# ESP32 LVGL support for LT768x

Tags: driver, esp32, lvgl

I need to use LVGL (Light and Versatile Graphics Library) running on ESP32 with a panel that uses a LT768x. I have it working with smaller panels using the ST7789 however I don't see any support for the LT768x.

Does anyone know of a driver for this chip?